# Universal configuration manager - quicker way to copy or download the settings?

Tags: server, window, universal, broker

I would like to copy or download the settings set in Universal configuration manager in windows 2012 server.
is there a way to do that?

the only  thing I could think of is to make screenshots of every page.

Thanks.